# i cannot connect server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";
import "react-mdl/extra/material.css";
import "react-mdl/extra/material.js";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(,document.getElementById("root"));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Error Message:

```
You must specify the "to" property ./src/index.js src/index.js:9

6 | import App from './App'; 7 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'; 8 | import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your `ReactDOM.render` method.

This method requires a `component` and an element.

In your code, you've specified the element but you forgot to specify the component.

You can do it like:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("root"));
```

which should fix your problem.